# Setting theme by time in emacs lisp

Tags: timer, emacs, themes

I am trying to set the theme for Emacs but I have been experiencing some errors. Currently my code is:

```lisp
;; theme
(defun set-theme-time ()
  (let ((light 'modus-operandi)
        (dark 'modus-vivendi))
    (load-theme light t t)
    (load-theme dark t t)
    (run-at-time "8:00" nil
      (lambda (light dark)
         (disable-theme dark)
         (enable-theme light))) 
    (run-at-time "17:00" nil
      (lambda (light dark)
         (disable-theme light)
         (enable-theme dark)))
    (message "Theme Loaded")))
(set-theme-time)
```

Everything in my config loads, and `message` does print `Theme Loaded` in the `*Messages*` buffer. However, the themes do not display, and after everything else has loaded I get this:

```
Error running timer: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (light dark) (disable-theme dark) (enable-theme light)) 0) [2 times]
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: Here is the working code:

```lisp
;; theme
(defun onoff (theme1 theme2)
    (disable-theme theme1)
    (enable-theme theme2))

(defun set-theme-time ()
  (let ((light 'modus-operandi)
        (dark 'modus-vivendi))
    (load-theme light t t)
    (load-theme dark t t)

    (run-at-time "8:00" nil #'onoff dark light)
    (run-at-time "17:00" nil #'onoff light dark)

    (message "Theme Loaded")))

(set-theme-time)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are using `lambda` or where you expect its arguments to come from. Did you perhaps mean something like this ...?

```
(defun set-theme-time ()
  (let ((light 'modus-operandi)
        (dark 'modus-vivendi)
        (offon (lambda (off on) (disable-theme off) (enable-theme on))))
   (load-theme light t t)
   (load-theme dark t t)
    
   (run-at-time "8:00" nil offon dark light)
   (run-at-time "17:00" nil offon light dark)

   (message "Theme Loaded")))
```

This is kind of clunky, though; perhaps it would make more sense for `offon` to be a separately defined named function which you could invoke by name `#'offon`.